# Use fluent API to enforce unique values based on date

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I am trying to build a simple application using Entity Framework Core and SQL. I have a table `Registries` that has the following fields:

```cs
RegistrationNumber (int, not null)
RegistryId (FK, int) - relation
RegistrationDate (Datetime, not null)
```

I would like that the `RegistrationNumber` to be unique for each different `RegistryId` so I have used the `ModelBuilder API` as following:

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Registry>().HasIndex(re => new { re.RegistrationNumber, re.RegistryId }).IsUnique();
}
```

Unfortunately, I have to implement a new change where the `RegistrationNumber` has to be unique per year. For example, I can have `RegistrationNumber: 1`, `RegistrationDate: 01/01/2021` but I could also have `RegistrationNumber:2`, `RegistrationDate: 01/01/2022`. I can't have `RegistrationNumber: 1`, `RegistrationDate: 02/01/2021`. (The values and the dates are random, there is no relation between `RegistrationNumber` and `RegistrationDate`.)

So, in order to implement this, I guess I have to remove the `HasIndex` for `RegistrationNumber` from the *ModelBuilder API* but I am not able to find another solution to achieve this using the *ModelBuilder API*. Would that be even possible?

Comment: Then hou have to add a `Year` column, which may be a persisted computed column based on `RegistrationDate` so you can use it in an index.

Comment: @GertArnold, thank you for your response, this is what I have implemented and works well.